# Restar dos lista en python

Tags: python

No tengo mucha experiencia en python. Después de crear el código que os muestro, me gustaría restar la lista (a) menos la (b). Hay algún método?

```
lista = [1, 10, 2, 6, 2, 0]

def mayor():
    a = []
    b = []
    a.append(lista[0:6:2])
    b.append(lista[1:6:2])
    #print(b)
    #print(a)
    print( "".join(map(str, b)))
    print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in a ) )

print(mayor())
```

Comment: A qué llamas "restar"? Obtener la diferencia elemento a elemento, por ejemplo, si una lista tiene un 3 en cierta posición y la otra tiene un 1, el resultado tendría un 3-1=2 en esa posición? O a obtener qué elementos son diferentes, como si fuera una resta de conjuntos, por ejemplo si una lista es `[1,2,3]` y la otra es `[1,3]` el resultado sería  `[2]`?

Comment: Hola, Daniel. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Estaba mirando tu consulta y la verdad no comprendo muy bien lo que deseas hacer. ¿Quieres restar elemento por elemento de cada lista de forma separada? ¿Quieres eliminar los elementos de una lista que estén en el otro? Edita, por favor, la pregunta y añade más información para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Te comento. Mi propósito era restar los números consecutivos de la lista “matriz”. Para hacerlo pensé la posibilidad de dividir la lista en dos  listas. Y luego, sacar el valor obsoluto . Obviamente, no tengo muchos conocimientos aún en python ni programación. Agradecería ayuda.Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que sean, por ejemplo:

```
a = [1, 9, 4, 0, 3, 10, 5]

b = [3, 10, 6, 0, 10, 4, 3]
```

Entonces bastaría con hacer:

```
diferencia = [e1 - e2 for e1, e2 in zip(a,b)] # Resultado: [-2, -1, -2, 0, -7, 6, 2]
```

Nótese cómo para realizar esta operación es imprescindible que las dos listas tengan la misma longitud.

Además se debe cuidar que los tipos de datos implicados en la operación resta sean compatibles entre sí.

Comment: Gracias por la contestación.

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera sería usar una función anónima (lambda function) y la función `map()`:

```
list1 = [2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4]
list2 = [4, 1, 2, 9, 7, 5]

product = list(map(lambda x,y: x-y ,list1,list2))
print(product)



# Resultado: [-2, 3, 3, -6, -2, 6, -1]
```

Aquí también es necesario que las dos listas tengan la misma cantidad de números. Espero haber ayudado

Comment: gracias cristian por aclalar lambda function

Comment: de nada :D y es Christian (con h)

Comment: ok, lo siento, igualmente gracias